# Send email by using R

Tags: r, email, automation

I am currently new to R programming and am in the process of learning how to send emails using R. Despite the abundance of online resources available, I have conducted research and gone through several YouTube tutorials, but unfortunately, I have not been successful so far. I am wondering if the issue lies with my VPN or if it is related to being within a company network.

I have attempted to use packages such as `sendmailR`, `mailR`, `blastula`, and `emayili`, but I have not been able to achieve success. Could anyone suggest the most suitable approach for my situation?

My confusions :

1. Is my SMTP configuration correct?
2. Am I using the correct port number?
3. Does my code contain any errors?

One of my trial below which I feel closest to success :

```
    require(emayili)
    require(dplyr)
   
    sender <- "abc@company123.com.my"
    recipient <- "abc@company123.com.my"
    
email <- envelope() %>%
  from(sender) %>%
  to(recipient) %>%
  subject("Internship_Learning") %>%
  text("Pass?")

smtp <- server(host = "123.45.678.901",
               port = 465,
               username = "abc@company123.com.my",
               password = "***",
               secure = "ssl"
)
smtp(email, verbose = TRUE)
```

Error message :

```
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/purrr_error_rate_excess>
Error in `rate_sleep()`:
! Request failed after 5 attempts.
---
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. └─emayili (local) smtp(email, verbose = TRUE)
 2.   └─purrr (local) send_mail(...) at emayili/R/server.R:190:4
 3.     └─purrr::rate_sleep(rate, quiet = quiet)
Run rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE) to see 3 hidden frames.
> rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE)
<error/purrr_error_rate_excess>
Error in `rate_sleep()`:
! Request failed after 5 attempts.
---
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. └─emayili (local) smtp(email, verbose = TRUE)
 2.   └─purrr (local) send_mail(...) at emayili/R/server.R:190:4
 3.     └─purrr::rate_sleep(rate, quiet = quiet)
 4.       └─purrr:::stop_rate_excess(rate)
 5.         └─cli::cli_abort(...)
 6.           └─rlang::abort(...)
```

As a reference, here is what I have (example) :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
host = "123.45.678.901"
```

is a fake IP address, the code will not work.
You better set a real IP address to make it run.

Comment: Hi @Ilja , because this is an example, hence I put the "fake" one as an example here. Even though I put the real one, I still not able to run it...

Comment: MTP port 465 is a deprecated standard for Secure SMTP (SMTPS). The Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) does not recommend its use. However, some legacy email systems may still use port 465 for SMTP with SSL/TLS encryption. 
Port 587 is the default port for SMTP submission on the modern web. Most SMTP servers support port 587 and it is useful for non-encrypted connections.

Comment: Okay... but, could you advise me why I have such error? How can I fix that...